# Identifying capitalized words in a text analysis

Tags: text

I would like to be able to identify those sentences that have a capitalized word somethere OTHER than the beginning of the sentence:

Be it so, then I answer'd,
I too haughty Shade also sing war, and a longer and greater one than any,

Comment: What have you tried? Why didn't that work? This question will be easier to answer and more useful for others if you add a minimal working example of the data, your working code attempt, and expected output format, showing specifically what you are working with. Please [edit] your question to [improve it](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). Include a minimum example of code that shows the problem and an example of the desired output.

Comment: Are you assuming no capitals in the middle of words? I assume the following sentence should not be returned: "TeX is a typesetting system."

Answer (score 1):

Let us define some sample text:

```
txt = "This is the first sentence. And this is a sentence with \
calitalized As. The string Anna is a name"
```

To analyze this text, we define a function that breaks the text into sentences  by:

```
sent = TextSentences[txt];
```

Then we search in every sentence capitalized words, discarding the word at the beginning. We the returns for every sentence a list containing sublists. The first gives the positions of the capitalize words, the second the words itself:

```
getCaps[txt_] := Module[{sent, caps, pos},
  sent = TextSentences[txt];
  res = (caps = 
       StringCases[#, RegularExpression["([A-Z]\\w+)"] -> "$1"];
      {pos = Select[StringPosition[#, caps], #[[1]] != 1 &], 
       StringTake[#, pos]}) & /@ sent
  ]
```

Applying this to our test text:

```
getCaps[txt]
{{{}, ""}, {{{41, 42}}, {"As"}}, {{{12, 15}}, {"Anna"}}}
```